# Slick Slider - How to Remove Specific Slides On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I am trying to add functionality to slick slider where when you click on a slide it will remove it from the slider.

I looked at the documentation on [Slick Sliders](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) website and it shows how to add/remove slides, but that only works for the last slide in the slider.

I am trying to make it work so you can remove a specific slide based on which one is clicked.

```html
<div class="slider add-remove slick-initialized slick-slider">
    <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 80px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" role="listbox">
            <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide100">
                <h3>1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-remove-slide">Remove Slide</a>
```

```js
$('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
  $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
  if (slideIndex !== 0){
    slideIndex--;
  }
});
```

EDIT: I added some more code to show how it is set up for [Slick slider HERE](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) this is set up to remove the last slide in the slider.

I'm trying to set it up so when the remove button is clicked on a slide that slide will be removed from the slider. The snippet I grabbed from the Slick Slider website only removes the last slide in the slider. So I'm trying to figure out how to remove a specific slide on click.

[image]

Comment: can you please post complete html code or screenshot?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I added the html code found on slick sliders website on how they set it up to remove the last slide. I also added a screenshot of my project to display what I am trying to do.

Comment: means you want to remove "Fade" area?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Not sure what you mean by "Fade" area? If you look at the screenshot each of those slides in the slider have a remove button on it. What I am trying to do is when clicked that slide should be removed from the slider. What the example on Slick Slider's website is doing is using a button outside the slider and is only removing the last slide in that slider, not a specific one like how I need it to. Trying to figure out how to modify the slick slider snippet to work with the functionality I need for this project. Sorry if not clear, if you have any other question let me know!

Comment: you problem is scattered can you please minimize extra code?

Comment: you will have to set id for each slide then on the basis  of id slide can be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://codepen.io/leggomuhgreggo/pen/WvpRgG?editors=001) is a CodePen with your solution

```js
console.clear();

$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true
});

$('.slide').on('click', function() {
  $('.slider').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-slide').index(this) - 1);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #102131;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.slider img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    <h1>slide 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    <h1>slide 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    <h1>slide 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    <h1>slide 4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    <h1>slide 5</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help! And love the image you chose to use haha

Comment: Another way to get the current index is:

`$('.slick-slide').index($('.slick-current'))`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.slick-slide').on('click', function() {
   var $indexid = $(this).attr("data-slick-index");
  $('.slick-slider').slick('slickRemove', $indexid);
});
```

Comment: Please, add a [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372). It would greatly improve its long-term value of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple actually

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.slick-slider .delete', {}, function() {
    $( this ).closest( '.slick-slide' ).remove();
} );
```